# STM32 RTC does not update when powered off

Tags: stm32

I am using the stm32F103R8T6.
and we are measuring time using RTC

it measures time well when the power is on and stores it well in backup registers
and when you reboot, the last value is successfully read from the backup register

The problem is that the time does not update when the power is turned off

I want the time to keep updating even when the power is off

In fact, I confirmed that the battery was well connected to the VBAT and that the voltage was normal at 3V even after the power was turned off

What's wrong with my code?

// rtc.c

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    rtc.c
  * @brief   This file provides code for the configuration
  *          of the RTC instances.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "rtc.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

RTC_HandleTypeDef hrtc;

/* RTC init function */
void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime = {0};
  RTC_DateTypeDef DateToUpdate = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */

  /** Initialize RTC Only
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = RTC_AUTO_1_SECOND;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUTSOURCE_ALARM;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Check_RTC_BKUP */
  /* USER CODE END Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date
  */
  sTime.Hours = 0x0;
  sTime.Minutes = 0x0;
  sTime.Seconds = 0x0;

  if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  DateToUpdate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  DateToUpdate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
  DateToUpdate.Date = 0x1;
  DateToUpdate.Year = 0x0;

  if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &DateToUpdate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}

void HAL_RTC_MspInit(RTC_HandleTypeDef* rtcHandle)
{

  if(rtcHandle->Instance==RTC)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_MspInit 0 */
    HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
    /* Enable BKP CLK enable for backup registers */
    __HAL_RCC_BKP_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* RTC clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_RTC_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_RTC_MspDeInit(RTC_HandleTypeDef* rtcHandle)
{

  if(rtcHandle->Instance==RTC)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_RTC_DISABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_MspDeInit 1 */
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */
```

// main.c

```
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  MX_ADC2_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  RTCTimerInit();
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      GetCurrentBCDTime();
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC|RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInit.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSE;
  PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCPCLK2_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

// my rtc.c

```
RTC_TimeTypeDef rtcTime;
RTC_DateTypeDef rtcDate;

void RTCTimerInit()
{
    rtcTime.Hours = HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR1);
    rtcTime.Minutes = HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR2);
    rtcTime.Seconds = HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR3);

    rtcDate.Year = HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR4);
    rtcDate.Date = HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR5);
    rtcDate.Month = HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR6);
    rtcDate.WeekDay = HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR7);

    HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &rtcTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);
    HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &rtcDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);
}

void GetCurrentBCDTime()
{
    static u8 oldSec = 255;

    HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &rtcTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);
    HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &rtcDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);

    if (oldSec != rtcTime.Seconds)
    {
        HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR1, rtcTime.Hours);
        HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR2, rtcTime.Minutes);
        HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR3, rtcTime.Seconds);

        HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR4, rtcDate.Year);
        HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR5, rtcDate.Date);
        HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR6, rtcDate.Month);
        HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR7, rtcDate.WeekDay);

    }

    oldSec = rtcTime.Seconds;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: How can you tell whether or not the time is updating while the power is off?  You're initializing all of the time/date registers to zero, and then restoring them from the RTC backup registers - which are certainly not going to change while the power is off.

Comment: @jasonharper 

hello 

As you said, the value of the backup register does not disappear even after rebooting
What I want is for time to pass even after the power is turned off, but in reality, the value written to the backup register at the end is read and time does not pass

How can I make time continue to flow even after the power is turned off??

Thanks.

Comment: You need to NOT initialize the time to zero, and not restore anything from the backup registers.

Comment: how can I set the default value to the current date from 19700101